# Python: find the inflection point of a logit regression model using statsmodel

Tags: python, statistics

I am using statsmodel as so in Python:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
```

And I have a dataframe with x1 values and d values. The d column is my dependent variable. I plot d vs x1 and get:

[image]

Now, I fit a logit regression model using statsmodel:

```
logit_mod = smf.logit('d ~ x1', data = df).fit()
print
print(logit_mod.summary())
logithat = logit_mod.predict(df)

plt.plot(df['x1'], logithat, 'o')
plt.scatter(df['x1'], df['d'], color='orange')
```

Result is this:

[image]

How do I obtain the value of the inflection point of that logit curve?

Thanks!

Comment: The logit function is symmetric around zero, or at probability 0.5. I think the inflection point is where the linear prediction is zero 0 = const + b * x_I, where b is the slope coefficient, so it should be `x_I = -params[0] / params[1]`. (not verified)

Comment: So do you mean `x_I = -logit_mod.params[0] / logit_mod.params[1]`?Because that returns 0.511, which is around what I'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pds
df1  = pds.DataFrame({'lgt' : logithat,'x':x1}).set_index('x')
grid = np.linspace(df1.index.min(),df1.index.max(),df1.shape[0]+1)
df2 = pds.DataFrame({'grid':grid}).reset_index().set_index('grid')
df2 = pds.concat([df1,df2],join='outer',axis=1)
df2['lgt_'] = df2['lgt'].interpolate()


inflexion       = df2['lgt_'].diff().argmax()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
df2['lgt_'].plot(ax=ax)
ax.vlines(inflexion,df2['lgt_'].min(),df2['lgt_'].ix[inflexion])
```

Comment: This is helpful! Although it returns a value of 0.94, so I think it's giving me something different from the inflection point. Could this value instead be the equilibrium point or where the curve begins to flatten?

Comment: This works if the x values are on an even spaced grid, or better, the predicted values are evaluated at an equal spaced grid of x. Otherwise the finite diff would be based on different increments of x.

Comment: Yes it s exact @user333700 it true on a equal spaced grid. So i will correct my answer..

Comment: However, there is no need to interpolate. You can just call `predict` with the grid, `logit_mod.predict(df_grid)`. (Logit is also supposed to have somewhere the analytical derivative calculations directly, but it's internally used for calculating Margins.)